# Meteor Server Side Rendering data

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

My problem is on Meteor project, using React and React Router v4 with Server Side Rendering.

I would like show my posts on client side. When my page is loaded, my posts Array is displayed, but after client load, my posts Array is empty.

My createContainer function :

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  const posts = Post.find({ 'draft': false }).fetch();
  return {
    posts: posts
  };
}, PostList);
```

The data on server are good, but on my client, the data is empty. Maybe my problem is on my routes ?

My routes on client side :

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <AppLayout exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <AppLayout exact path="/blog" component={Blog} title={Trans.page.blog.title} />
        <AppLayout path='/blog/:slug' component={Article} title={Trans.page.blog.title} subtitle />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

And my routes on server side :

```
const Routes = (props) => {
  const context = {};
  return (
    <StaticRouter location={props.location} context={context}>
      <Switch>
        <AppLayout exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <AppLayout exact path="/blog" component={Blog} title={Trans.page.blog.title} />
        <AppLayout path='/blog/:slug' component={Article} title={Trans.page.blog.title} subtitle />
      </Switch>
    </StaticRouter>
  );
}
```

My problem is that the data loaded on the server side does not stay on the client once loaded :(

Anyone have idea ?

Than you community !

Comment: Sounds like you might not have subscribed to the data on the client side?

Comment: Nop, i don't have subscripted on client side because my data is showing, i don't understand why i need to subscribe ^^

Comment: You need to make the data available to the client so it can render it and it's updates. It sounds like the data is being rendered on the server then when the client code goes to take over, it renders all the data it has (none) leaving your page empty

Comment: This article explains why: https://medium.com/meteor-js/data-flow-from-the-database-to-the-ui-three-layers-of-meteor-d5e208b466c3

Answer (score 0):

A subscription needs to be made on the client side, as indeed it does not get the data otherwise.

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
     Meteor.subscribe('subName')
  }
  const posts = Post.find({ 'draft': false }).fetch();
  return {
    posts: posts
  };
}, PostList);
```

You first receive the data because they are available on server side automatically. Which also means you have to be very careful with the data you fetch, because the server-side rendering will not use the publish method as a reference. Your filter in the Collection.find({}) has to be relevant to the server as well.